# Phone gap camera - is there a more powerful option?

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking to build a companion photo capture app for my photo capture website.  I was planning to do this with phone gap.

Upon triggering the camera I want to grab a frame (a still, really) up to five times a second and send it to the server (barring any surprises, The sending part should already be dealt with in code I have).  I suppose the realtime video from the camera itself should be displayed to the user as well, though I could just use the stop motion frames for that part.

Unfortunately, according to the phone gap docs, one can only launch the phone's cam app, manually take a picture, then return the user to the app.

I am looking into plugins, but I don't see any massive phonegap plugin repository out there, so I am not sure where to begin.  I am just rambling now, so here is a list of bulleted questions:

- Is there a plugin out there that does something like this already?
- Is there a giant repository of phone gap plugins that I am too foolish to find?
- If I try to roll my own java plugin (this is for an android app), what am I really getting myself into?  Will I need to know enough to just make the damned thing native?  I am pretty exclusively in the JS world at the moment, and am trying to get this out the door asap.
- Am I missing something and there *is* a way to to this with vanilla phone gap?
- Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm searching for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The phonegap plugins are here:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins